# RSS feed not showing an image, failing to add podcast to itunes

Tags: xml, wordpress, plugins, rss, itunes

I have enabled thumbnails in my themes functions.php via

`add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );`

But when I view the categorized posts feed for the podcast, there is not image, thus failing to give the feed over to itunes.

What other things are required to set the  in the xml feed?

Thanks!

### Update

I ended up finding out that wordpress auto applies 404 to the header of responses that are not associated with wordpress content. This made what should have been a simple workaround more difficult.

After that I opted to just use blubrry plugin, and its working fine with all my custom post types. Its amazing what wordpress makes simple, and in turn makes complex.

I still haven't looked into the plugins code to see how they got around the issue, once I do I will try to update this post.

Answer (score 0):

[I had a really difficult time](http://blog.muschamp.ca/2013/09/07/thumbnails-in-rss-feeds-proves-non-trivial-in-wordpress/) getting featured images to work perfectly IE 100% valid RSS. I finally settled on [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/featured-images-for-rss-feeds/). I have no idea if this plugin will help with iTunes/podcasts but invalid XML/RSS feeds definitely messes with some readers and SimplePie.